# Main activity calling seperate activities for each tab in actionbar(support.v7)

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar-compat

i am using actionbar(support.v7) with 4 tabs using fragments. I want each tab to have a separate activity rather than a common activity calling fragments?

**ApplicationMainTabsActivity**

```
public class ApplicationMainTabsActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    ActionBar.Tab Tab1, Tab2, Tab3,Tab4;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        String label1 = getResources().getString(R.string.label1);
        Tab1 = actionBar.newTab();
        Tab1.setText(label1);
        ApplicationTabListener<Fragment1> tl = new ApplicationTabListener<Fragment1>(this,label1, Fragment1.class);
        Tab1.setTabListener(tl);
        actionBar.addTab(Tab1);

        String label2 = getResources().getString(R.string.label2);
        Tab2 = actionBar.newTab();
        Tab2.setText(label2);
        ApplicationTabListener<Fragment2> t2 = new ApplicationTabListener<Fragment2>(this,label2, Fragment2.class);
        Tab2.setTabListener(t2);
        actionBar.addTab(Tab2);

        String label3 = getResources().getString(R.string.label3);
        Tab3 = actionBar.newTab();
        Tab3.setText(label3);
        ApplicationTabListener<Fragment3> t3 = new ApplicationTabListener<Fragment3>(this,label3, Fragment3.class);
        Tab3.setTabListener(t3);
        actionBar.addTab(Tab3);

        String label4 = getResources().getString(R.string.label4);
        Tab4 = actionBar.newTab();
        Tab4.setText(label4);
        ApplicationTabListener<Fragment4> t4 = new ApplicationTabListener<Fragment4>(this,label4, Fragment4.class);
        Tab4.setTabListener(t4);
        actionBar.addTab(Tab4);
    }
```

**ApplicationTabListener.java**

```
final class ApplicationTabListener<T extends Activity> implements ActionBar.TabListener {
    private Fragment mFragment;
    private final Activity mActivity;
    private final String mTag;
    private final Class<T> mClass;
    private final Bundle mArgs;


    /**

     * Constructor used each time a new tab is created.
     * 
     * @param activity
     *            The host Activity, used to instantiate the fragment
     * @param tag
     *            The identifier tag for the fragment
     * @param clz
     *            The fragment's Class, used to instantiate the fragment
     */

    public ApplicationTabListener(Activity activity, String tag, Class<T> clz) {
        this(activity, tag, clz, null);
    }






 public ApplicationTabListener(Activity activity, String tag, Class<T> clz, Bundle args) {
        mActivity = activity;
        mTag = tag;
        mClass = clz;
        mArgs = args;
    }




    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // Check if the fragment is already initialized
        if (mFragment == null) {
            // If not, instantiate and add it to the activity
            mFragment = Fragment.instantiate(mActivity, mClass.getName());
            ft.add(R.id.action_bar_activity_content, mFragment, mTag);
        } else {
            // If it exists, simply attach it in order to show it
            ft.replace(R.id.action_bar_activity_content,mFragment);
       }
    }



    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        if (mFragment != null) {
            // Detach the fragment, because another one is being attached
          ft.remove(mFragment);

        }
  }



    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // User selected the already selected tab. Usually do nothing.
    }
}
```

**Fragment1.java**

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment{
     @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Inflate the layout for this fragment
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, container, false);
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have separate activity for each Tab which was used to be as in TabActivity. And it's deprecated. You need to attach fragments in order to use it. Otherwise you need to build your own custom TabActivity.

Comment: I want to keep the activities separate for respective tabs.I don't want to use TabActivity just because it is deprecated.Is there any other way to do so ?

Comment: Well, I have another solution that I used in one of my applications. Instead of using different activities for each Tab, you can have different bunch of Fragments for each Tab. That will do the same thing as you want. Check out my GitHub repository, I have a sample application showing how to use it. [GitHub Link](https://github.com/osayilgan/samples/tree/master/SampleApp)